# How to set the thickness of plot ticks?

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

I want to draw a plot with specific ticks. So I added the `Ticks` property. Now, I also wish to enhance the ticks, so I tried to manipulate that using `TicksStyle`. However, I get horizontal ticks on the X axis. How should I change that?
I considered drawing lines on the graph, but I hope there's a simpler solution.

Example

```
Print[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, +5}, TicksStyle -> {Thickness[0.1], Automatic}]];
```

[image]

Comment: That's just because Thickness[0.1] is super thick after factoring in the overall plot horizontal size. Try AbsoluteThickness[3] for 3 points at 72DPI (the default is 0.5)

Comment: If you need both axes, try `TicksStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[3], Automatic},{AbsoluteThickness[3], Automatic}}`